# How to merge Flowfiles in Apache Nifi after using SplitJson

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an array consisting of n elements, and each element needs to be processed individually. After processing, they need to be merged back into a single array.

I used SplitJson to split this array into n Flowfiles for processing. I noticed that each Flowfile has been indexed, and I can also see the total number of elements in my array. How can I merge these elements back into a single array with n elements as it was originally?

Answer (score 0):

Use MergeContent Processor with Defragmentation in Merge Strategy

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47cvf.png)